# Sum of binomial coefficients multiplied by powers of two and something else

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How can I prove the following identity:

$$\sum_{0\le i\le n} (i+1)2^i {{2n-i}\choose{n}} =(2n+1){{2n}\choose{n}}$$

A few words as to why I need the proof.

I noticed that if we write numbers of the form $n2^{n-1}$ (so, 0, 1, 4, 12, 32 etc.) on the sides of Pascal triangle and continue to build Pascal triangle by the same rule as usually, then numbers $n{{2n}\choose{n}}$ (2, 12, 60, etc.) emerge on the diagonal.

[image]

Here is the picture showing ratios of the numbers in the new triangle to the corresponding numbers in the usual Pascal triangle

[image]

One can write down the generating function with two variables for the entries in our new triangle.
Let $a_{i,j}$ be the entry in the i-th column and j-th row, then $$F(x,y) = \sum a_{i, j} x^i y^j = \frac{ \frac{x-x^2}{(1-2x)^2} + \frac{y-y^2}{(1-2y)^2} }{1-x-y}$$

From here I obtained the aforementioned identity comparing the coefficients of $x^n y^n$.

But I don't know how to prove it.  The upper coefficient in the sum depends on $i$, so this formula has no algebraic meaning. Induction doesn't help too.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: I found the previous question and answer by copying the MathJax for your formula, and pasting it into the "raw query" box on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/)